# How to integrate a booking form?

Tags: 7, webforms

... preferably with PHP. I am new to Drupal.

My goal is to integrate a page into an already existing project which enables to give to users the possibility to book a Hotelroom or a flight ticket while the Administrator (me) then collects the submitted information and validates the choice in the backend.

I have done this countless of times from scratch in PHP with POST. But on Drupal, when I try to integrate HTML and PHP code into a new webform or new article page, it doesnt really render it.

Comment: Can you edit your question and explain what you have already tried and what the goal is. We will need some more information in order to help you.

Comment: I edited my comment. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading your question I would do the following:

Create a custom module with a custom block that holds the booking form. This way you can add the booking form on whatever page you like with the [Context module](https://www.drupal.org/project/context) for example.

The [Drupal 7 example module](https://www.drupal.org/project/examples) can show and teach you how to create a block in a custom module.

Comment: Not 100% what I wanted but it does what I intend to do. I would also like to add that I just learned also that with the webform module you can send to users automated emails after they submit their form.

Comment: If you want to have the built-in functionality from a Webform then you'll need a custom module that alters the webform with function hook_form_FORM_ID_alter() and render your booking form where you want it.

Answer (score 1):

By altering the Webform you can achieve. I know this is not the exact solution but you can achieve by doing some customization.

Alter webform and add php/Html code. 
Implement the "`hook_form_FORM_ID_alter`".

```
function YOUR_MODULE_form_FORM_ID_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    //check how you can use #submit/#validate to call custom function
    //Write your code in custom function. 
}
```